# Unset the key in multidimensional array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to unset the key which is equal to 'null' in my multidimensional array but the codes I've work with is not working so I tried to run it online. But even in online it does not work so I think there is something wrong in my codes.

My link for code is https://eval.in/591584

And this is my array:

```
$array = array(
'6' => array(
    'null' =>array(
        'null'=>array(
               '11:04'=>array(
                    'id' => '22'
                )
        )
    ),
    '1'=>array(
        '2'=>array(
               '11:04'=>array(
                    'id' => '22'
                )
           )
      ),
  )
);
```

What I want is to remove the key with name `null`.

The output I want is below where the null key is unset:

```
$array = array(
'6' => array(
    '1'=>array(
        '2'=>array(
               '11:04'=>array(
                    'id' => '22'
                )
           )
      ),
  )
);
```

The code I've done so far is:

```
 foreach($array as $devp => $dev){
    foreach($dev as $comp => $com){

      if($comp == null){
         unset($array[$devp][$comp]);
      }
    }
  }
```

But it's not working. I declared this condition `($comp == null)` as comparing If `$comp` is equal to null. It should unset the array. What am I missing please help me.

Comment: In your code `'null'` is a string and not a `null` type.

Comment: `if($comp == 'null'){`. Use it

Comment: it should like https://eval.in/591587

Answer (score 1):

In PHP `null` is a special datatype. And your key with value `'null'` is a string.

So proper comparison is:

```
if ($comp == 'null') {    // see quotes?
    // do something
}
```